# Sequence only with hours and minutes

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I add a sequence only with hours and minutes? from the configuration if I write `%(h24)s%(min)s` on `prefix`, it shows something like 23461

```html
<data noupdate="1">

        
        <record id="seq_order" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">test Order</field>
            <field name="code">test.model</field>
            <field name="prefix"></field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
        </record>

    </data>
```

Comment: what is wrong with '23461'? 23 is the hour, 46 is the minute and 1 is the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to do this with how `ir.sequence` works. You would need to extend the model and add functionality to not display the actually sequence number (but this may defeat the purpose of using a sequence all together, I'll let you decide that).

```py
class IrSequence(models.Model):
    """ Sequence model.

    The sequence model allows to define and use so-called sequence objects.
    Such objects are used to generate unique identifiers in a transaction-safe
    way.
    """
    _inherit = 'ir.sequence'
    skip = fields.Boolean('Skip Sequence Number', help='Mark to true to not display the sequence number in the sequence, only use the prefix/suffix.')

    def _next(self):
        """
        Override this to extend ir.sequence to not use the next
        sequence number.
        """     

        ...

    def get_next_char(self, number_next):
        """
        Override this to extend ir.sequence to not use the next
        sequence number.
        """        

        ...
```